# Excel Sum values by extracting numbers from single multi-line cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

```
AL-CHE-P1-1518   ---     270  

AL-CHE-P2-1318    ---    280  

AL-MAT-P1-1218     ---   280  

AL-MAT-P4-0918      --- 40
```

all these data are **inside same cell C2**, my aim is to derive a formula to sum

```
 270+280+280+40
```

in cell D2

tried `regextract(c2,"\d(.*)\n")` but only the first "270" is extracted, I need help, searched through all forums, couldn't get exact match, it will save me huge time if anyone could give me some hint on how to derive the sum inside same cell string

Comment: you want that in google sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(C2,CHAR(10))," \d+")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you can only accomplish this via a UDF:

```
Function ReturnSum(rng As Range) As Long

    Dim arr As Variant

    arr = Split(rng.Value, Chr(10) & Chr(10))

    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        ReturnSum = ReturnSum + Trim(Split(arr(i), " --- ")(1))
    Next i

End Function
```

[image: img1]

Comment: Wanna bet that the only way is UDF in Excel?

Answer (score 2):

In Excel the formula is a bit more complicated and an array formula:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--MID(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)),FIND("---",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)))+3,99),0))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when Exiting Edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Yet again, black magic... I imagine there are very few people around that can write a formula to achieve this!